# Bootstrap selectpicker live search: on keyup call ajax to fill options

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I wish to customize [bootsrap selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) but I'm really not able to understand how to catch the search text on keyup blocking the default dropdown menu from showing.

Anyone did this before and may help me on finding the right way?

Here it is what I wish to do:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: The code is not different from the one you can find here https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search (paragraph "Live search")

Comment: Without your own code examples of what you have tried the only suggestion I can give is to hook into the listener(s) bootstrap adds to that element. This is a lot of work since bootstrap runs on page load and adds listeners to everything. You'll need to remove their event listeners, attach your own, and pass through/back to their listeners if you still want everything to work like normal still after you have done your processing.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones looking for a solution, the plugin's author just suggested me this resource https://github.com/truckingsim/Ajax-Bootstrap-Select .
It seems ok.